# DatagramSocket throws Exception while sending to multicast group

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, multicast, datagram

I try to send some data to a multicast group. This worked for sometime, but now I get an exception.
The Exception says that the hostname can't be resolved (HRESULT: 0x80072AF9).

The hostname he tries to resolve is the ip address (224.5.6.7). This exception doesn't occurs on my Surface RT but on the Surface Pro.

With this sample I could produce the error:

```
    private async void Test()
    {

        try
        {
            var socket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket();
            var localAdress = CurrentIPAddress();
            var port = "40404";
            const string M_GROUP = "224.5.6.7";

            socket.MessageReceived += (sender, ev) => {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

            };

            await socket.BindEndpointAsync(new HostName(localAdress), port);
            socket.JoinMulticastGroup(new HostName(M_GROUP));


            //HRESULT: 0x80072AF9
            var stream = await socket.GetOutputStreamAsync(
                                         new HostName(M_GROUP),
                                         port);
            await stream.WriteAsync(new byte[] { 3 }.AsBuffer());

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            throw;
        }
    }

    private string CurrentIPAddress()
    {
        var icp = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        if (icp != null && icp.NetworkAdapter != null)
        {
            var hostname =
                NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
                    .SingleOrDefault(
                        hn =>
                        hn.IPInformation != null && hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter != null
                        && hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId
                        == icp.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId);

            if (hostname != null)
            {
                // the ip address
                return hostname.CanonicalName;
            }
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

The Exception happens when GetOutputStreamAsync is called.

In both Systems the Sockets are bound to an ipv4 address.
Both Systems are up do date. (29. May 2014)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a known bug in Windows 8.1: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/908c6c55-fb1d-48ed-8275-835efcca9294/multicast-issue-when-migrating-from-win8-to-win81?forum=winappswithcsharp